# Sum results of a few queries and then find top 5 in SQL

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 queries:

```
table: pageview
SELECT event_id, count(*) AS pageviews 
FROM pageview 
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY pageviews DESC, rand()
LIMIT 1000

table: upvote
SELECT event_id, count(*) AS upvotes 
FROM upvote
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY upvotes DESC, rand()
LIMIT 1000

table: attending
SELECT event_id, count(*) AS attendants
FROM attending
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY attendants DESC, rand()
LIMIT 1000
```

I'd like to combine the `event_id`s of all 3 queries ordered by amount and then choose the top 5. How do I do that?

**EDIT: HERE IS WHAT I DID TO MAKE IT HAPPEN:**

```
SELECT event_id, sum(amount) AS total
FROM (
(SELECT event_id, count(*) AS amount
FROM   pageview 
GROUP  BY event_id
ORDER  BY amount DESC, rand()
LIMIT  1000)

UNION ALL
(SELECT event_id, count(*) as amount
FROM   upvote
GROUP  BY event_id
ORDER  BY amount DESC, rand()
LIMIT  1000)

UNION ALL
(SELECT event_id, count(*) as amount
FROM   attending
GROUP  BY event_id
ORDER  BY amount DESC, rand()
LIMIT  1000)
) x
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY  sum(amount) DESC
LIMIT  5;
```

Comment: How do you determine the top 5 of 3 distinct groups? Each could theoretically have 5 unique ID's not in the other lists. Do you sum them?

Comment: Define "combine". Add up the counts or just UNION the query results? Define "amount". Each count separately and compare `pageviews` to `upvotes` to `attendants`? or add them for each `event_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `UNION` the resulting rows of all three queries and then pick the 5 rows with the highest `amount`:

```sql
(SELECT event_id, count(*) AS amount
FROM   pageview 
GROUP  BY event_id
ORDER  BY pageviews DESC, rand()
LIMIT  1000)

UNION ALL
(SELECT event_id, count(*)
FROM   upvote
GROUP  BY event_id
ORDER  BY upvotes DESC, rand()
LIMIT  1000)

UNION ALL
(SELECT event_id, count(*)
FROM   attending
GROUP  BY event_id
ORDER  BY attendants DESC, rand()
LIMIT  1000)

ORDER  BY 2 DESC
LIMIT  5;
```

[The manual:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html)

> To apply `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` to an individual `SELECT`, place the
> clause inside the parentheses that enclose the `SELECT`.

`UNION ALL` to keep duplicates.

---

To **add the counts for every `event_id`**:

```sql
SELECT event_id, sum(amount) AS total
FROM (
   (SELECT event_id, count(*) AS amount
    FROM   pageview 
    GROUP  BY event_id
    ORDER  BY pageviews DESC, rand()
    LIMIT  1000)
    
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT event_id, count(*)
    FROM   upvote
    GROUP  BY event_id
    ORDER  BY upvotes DESC, rand()
    LIMIT  1000)
    
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT event_id, count(*)
    FROM   attending
    GROUP  BY event_id
    ORDER  BY attendants DESC, rand()
    LIMIT  1000)
    ) x
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY sum(amount) DESC
LIMIT  5;
```

The tricky part here is that not every `event_id` will be present in all three base queries. So take care that a `JOIN` does not lose rows completely and additions don't turn out `NULL`.

Use `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`. You don't want to remove identical rows, you want to add them up.

`x` is a table alias and shorthand for `AS x`. It is required for for a subquery to have a name. Can be any other name here.

The SOL feature `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not implemented in MySQL (last time I checked), so you have to make do with `UNION`. `FULL OUTER JOIN` would join all three base queries without losing rows.

#### Answer to follow-up question

```sql
SELECT event_id, sum(amount) AS total
FROM (
   (SELECT event_id, count(*) / 100 AS amount
    FROM   pageview ... )
    
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT event_id, count(*) * 5 
    FROM   upvote ... )
    
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT event_id, count(*) * 10
    FROM   attending ... )
    ) x
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY  sum(amount) DESC
LIMIT  5;
```

Or, to use the base counts in multiple ways:

```sql
SELECT event_id
      ,sum(CASE source
              WHEN 'p' THEN amount / 100
              WHEN 'u' THEN amount * 5
              WHEN 'a' THEN amount * 10
              ELSE 0
           END)  AS total
FROM (
   (SELECT event_id, 'p'::text AS source, count(*) AS amount
    FROM   pageview ... )
    
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT event_id, 'u'::text, count(*)
    FROM   upvote ... )
    
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT event_id, 'a'::text, count(*)
    FROM   attending ... )
    ) x
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC
LIMIT  5;
```

Comment: Brandstetter, I believe the answer is the second one - say that `event_id=1` will correspond to 3 pageviews, 2 upvotes, and 1 attendant, I'd like the final amount associated with it to be 6. Then for exmaple `event_id=2` has 0 pageviews, 14 upvotes, and 0 attendees, the final value will be 14. Once I sum them together, I would like to take the top 5 results.

Comment: follow on question: say I want to calculate the final value for `event_id` as something like this ((pageviews/100) + upvotes*5 + attendants*10). How would I do this?

Comment: Also, what does the`x` before `group by` mean?

Comment: @Andypandy: I added info to my answer.