# Subtract two columns of different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, aggregate-functions, subtraction

I have two unrelated tables:

```
contribution(id,amount, create_at, user_id)

solicitude(id, amount, create_at, status_id, type_id, user_id)
```

I need to subtract the sum of the amount of the contribution and of the solicitude from a user, but that result can't to be negative.

How can I do this? Function or query?
I tried this query:

```
SELECT  sum(contribution.amount)
- (SELECT sum(solicitude.amount) 
   FROM solicitude 
   WHERE user_id = 1 AND status_id = 1) as total
FROM contribution 
WHERE contribution.user_id = 1
```

Comment: `but that result can't to be negative`. Please elaborate. And what's wrong with the query you have? The syntax can be simplified, but it does the job nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret your remark `but that result can't to be negative` as requirement to return 0 instead of negative results. The simple solution is [**`GREATEST()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST):

```
SELECT GREATEST(sum(amount)
      - (SELECT sum(amount)
         FROM   solicitude 
         WHERE  status_id = 1
         AND    user_id = 1), 0) AS total
FROM   contribution
WHERE  user_id = 1;
```

Otherwise, I kept your original query, which is fine.

For other cases with the possible result that no row could be returned I would replace with *two* sub-selects. But the use of the aggregate function *guarantees* a result row, even if the given `user_id` is not found at all. Compare:

- [Get n grouped categories and sum others into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560381/get-n-grouped-categories-and-sum-others-into-one/30598887#30598887)

If the result of the subtraction would be `NULL` (because no row is found or the sum is `NULL`), `GREATEST()` will also return `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an outer query to check the total value:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN total > 0 THEN total ELSE 0 END AS total
FROM (
    SELECT 
          sum(contribution.amount) - (SELECT sum(solicitude.amount) 
          FROM solicitude 
          WHERE user_id = 1 AND status_id = 1) as total
       FROM contribution 
       WHERE 
       contribution .user_id = 1
    ) alias;
```

This solution is OK, but I suggest an alternative approach. Check how this query works:

```
with contribution as (
    select user_id, sum(amount) as amount from contribution
    group by 1),
solicitude as (
    select user_id, sum(amount) as amount from solicitude
    where status_id = 1
    group by 1)
select 
    c.user_id, c.amount as contribution, s.amount as solitude,
    case when c.amount > s.amount then c.amount - s.amount else 0 end as total
from contribution c
join solicitude s on c.user_id = s.user_id;
```

---

I made a simple test, just out of curiosity, on this setup:

```
create table public.solicitude (
    id integer,
    amount numeric,
    create_at timestamp without time zone,
    status_id integer,
    type_id integer,
    user_id integer
);

create table public.contribution (
    id integer,
    amount numeric,
    create_at timestamp without time zone,
    user_id integer
);

insert into contribution (user_id, amount)
select (random()* 50)::int, (random()* 100)::int
from generate_series(1, 4000000);

insert into solicitude (user_id, amount, status_id)
select (random()* 50)::int, (random()* 100)::int, 1
from generate_series(1, 4000000);
```

Results (msecs):

```
Erwin's solution with greatest():  922, 905, 922, 904, 904, 904, 905, 912, 905, 922
My solution with an outer query:   796, 795, 814, 814, 815, 795, 815, 796, 815, 796
```

Comment: I think this is more expensive and verbose than it needs to be.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Do you mean the second query?

Comment: @klin: Yes, the second in particular, CTEs are more expensive and not necessary here. But also the first: one more query level than necessary, and `GREATEST()` would simplify further.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - The second query is intentionally verbose. This is an easy to understand and easy to modify example of how to join *aggregated* tables. Besides, sometimes I feel the need to write something nice. And this query is simply beautiful, isn't it? As regards `greatest`, I fully agree. I just forgot that such a thing exists ;)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - actually my solution with an outer query seems to be faster.

Answer (score -1):

You have to join the tables

```
SELECT sum(c.amount) - s.total 
FROM contribution c inner join  (SELECT user_id, sum(solicitude.amount) total
FROM solicitude  GROUP BY c.user_id HAVING user_id = 1 AND status_id = 1  )s
on c.user_id=s.user_id GROUP BY c.user_id,s.total HAVING c.user_id = 1
```

EDIT: I forgot an alias