# PostgreSQL lead() issue with camelCase column

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

So I'm trying to query a time card table whose structure is like this

```
employeeId | clockInTime| clockOutTime
-----------+------------+--------------
   555     | 1462797450 | 1462785465 
   555     | 1462883850 | 1462871850 
   111     | 1463056650 | 1463044650 <== skip this
   555     | 1463143050 | 1463131050 <== get this
   555     | 1463229426 | 1463245655 <== but not this
```

What I'm trying to do is select all rows between two values but also the next row after that group of rows for that employee regardless of the value

This is my query

```
select "clockInTime", "clockOutTime", lead("clockInTime",1)
from "timeCard"
where "clockInTime" between 1462797450 and 1462883850
and "employeeId" = 555
```

but I get this error:

> error: function lead(bigint, integer) does not exist

But when I remove the double quotes from `lead()` I only end up getting this because my column names are camelCase:

> error: column "clockintime" does not exist

I'm using node.js and the node-pg client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not "*remove the double quotes from `lead()`*". The error message reveals that you actually removed the double quotes from `"clockInTime"`:

> ```
> error: column "clockintime" does not exist
> ```

Consider:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

The long and the short of it: Don't use caMelCase identifiers with Postgres if you can avoid it:

---

As for the task you describe:

> select all rows between two values but also the next row after that group of rows for that employee

The `OVER` clause was missing from the window function [`lead()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) like [@Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37312245/939860) pointed out. But even with the syntax error fixed, `lead()` (or any other window function) does not seem like the right approach to get what you ask for. It adds a column to every row in the result, while you want to add a *row* to the set.

I suggest `UNION ALL` and `ORDER BY` / `LIMIT 1` to add the "next" row to the result set:

```
SELECT *
FROM   "timeCard"
WHERE  "employeeId" = 555
AND    "clockInTime" BETWEEN 1462797450 AND 1462883850

UNION ALL
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT *
FROM   "timeCard"
WHERE  "employeeId" = 555
AND    "clockInTime" > 1462883850
ORDER  BY "clockInTime"
LIMIT  1
);
```

A multicolumn **index** on `("employeeId", "clockInTime")` would make this very fast, even for big tables.

If `"clockInTime"` is not defined *unique*, you may want to add more expressions to `ORDER BY` to get a deterministic result in case of ties.

Parentheses are required to add `LIMIT` or `ORDER BY` to an individual leg of a `UNION` query. Example:

- [Get n grouped categories and sum others into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560381/get-n-grouped-categories-and-sum-others-into-one/30598887#30598887)

If you want the leading rows sorted as well:

```
(
SELECT *
FROM   "timeCard"
WHERE  "employeeId" = 555
AND    "clockInTime" BETWEEN 1462797450 AND 1462883850
ORDER  BY "clockInTime"
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT *
FROM   "timeCard"
WHERE  "employeeId" = 555
AND    "clockInTime" > 1462883850
ORDER  BY "clockInTime"
LIMIT  1
);
```

Comment: I see thank you and the reason i am using camelCase is because i want to keep it all consistent throughout the server and front end.

Comment: @Darkrum: Note the parentheses I added.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `over` clause.  I'm not sure what logic you are looking for exactly, but something like:

```
select "clockInTime", "clockOutTime",
       lead("clockInTime", 1) over (order by clickInTime)
from "timeCard"
where "clockInTime" between 1462797450 and 1462883850 and "employeeId" = 555;
```

Typically, you would want this per employee:

```
select "clockInTime", "clockOutTime",
        lead("clockInTime", 1) over (partition by "employeeid" order by clickInTime)
from "timeCard"
where "clockInTime" between 1462797450 and 1462883850 and "employeeId" = 555;
```

Comment: nope i got this when doing that error: syntax error at or near "over"

Comment: and isn't over optional?

Comment: No, because lead it's a window function.

Comment: @Darkrum . . . Are you sure you are using Postgres?

Comment: yes i am although it is a old version 8.0.2 because we are developing against aws redshift.

Comment: @Darkrum . . . Redshit supports `lead()`:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LEAD.html.