# Select first 50 rows then order

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

Is it possible to select the first 50 rows in Postgres with `select * from yellow_tripdata_staging fetch first 50 rows only` and **after** that sort the results by column?

If so, how?

edit:  the table is really big, and is not really important which rows i get.

this question was because i was using Redash to visualise the data and was getting some weird order on the sorted results.then i realized that the column i was using to order was not numerical but char, which causes values like 11 and 10 to come before 2 and 3.

Im sorry for this dumb question

Comment: There is no such thing as "the first 50 rows" in a SQL table or unordered result set.  You need to be more specific about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: oh yes, it was as you said in " just mean to fetch the "first" 50 rows according to current physical order" i forgot about this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear how your "first 50 rows" are identified and in what order they shall be returned. There is no "natural order" in tables of a relational database. No guarantees without explicit `ORDER BY`.

However, there ***is*** a current physical order of rows you can (ab-)use. Typically that's the order in which rows have been inserted - as long as nothing else has happened to that table. But the RDBMS is free to change the physical order any time, so the physical order is not reliable. Results can and will change with write operations to the table (including `VACUUM` or other utility commands).

Let's call your sort column `sort_col`.

```sql
(  -- parentheses required
TABLE yellow_tripdata_staging LIMIT 50
)
UNION ALL 
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT *
FROM  (TABLE yellow_tripdata_staging OFFSET 50) sub
ORDER  BY sort_col
);
```

More explanation (incl. `TABLE` and parentheses):

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from-in-psql/30276023#30276023)
- [Get n grouped categories and sum others into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560381/get-n-grouped-categories-and-sum-others-into-one/30598887#30598887)

***Or***, assuming `sort_col` is defined `NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   yellow_tripdata_staging
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN row_number() OVER () > 50 THEN sort_col END NULLS FIRST;
```

The window function `row_number()` is allowed to appear in the `ORDER BY` clause.

`row_number() OVER ()` (with empty `OVER` clause) will attach serial numbers according to the current physical order of row - all the disclaimers above still apply.

The `CASE` expression replaces the first 50 row numbers with NULL, which sort first due to attached `NULLS FIRST`. In effect, the first 50 rows are unsorted the rest is sorted by `sort_col`.

***Or***, if you actually mean to take the first 50 rows according to `sort_col` and leave them unsorted, while the rest is to be sorted:

```
SELECT *
FROM   yellow_tripdata_staging
ORDER  BY GREATEST (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY sort_col), 50);
```

***Or***, if you just mean to fetch the "first" 50 rows according to current physical order or some other undisclosed (more reliable) criteria, you need a subquery or CTE to sort those 50 rows in the outer `SELECT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (TABLE yellow_tripdata_staging LIMIT 50) sub
ORDER  BY sort_col;
```

You need to define your requirements clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by two *different* columns.  For instance:

```
select yts.*
from (select yts.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from yellow_tripdata_staging yts
     ) yts
order by (seqnum <= 50)::int desc,
         (case when seqnum <= 50 then id end),
         col
```