# How to check if a table is empty and if so, check in another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

I have two views: `current_campaign` and `last_campaign`:
`current_campaign` always has one row or none.
`last_campaign` always has one row.

I have another view that needs to get information from one of these:  `contributors`.

If `current_campaign` has one row, I need to give it the preference.
If `current_campaign` is empty, then I can get information from `last_campaign`.
Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean with "*visions*"? Are you talking about tables? Views? Materialized views? Functions?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Also, the word `vision` isn't really a SQL term, so I assume you intend "table" or "view".

Comment: Hint: use `EXISTS()` and/or `NOT EXISTS()`

Comment: Paste the script here ,what you did so far?

Comment: I took the liberty to replace the term "vision" with "view",  presuming that's what you meant.

Comment: Yes, I meant view ( i didn't even knew that "vision" existed ). What I did was that ( and it seems to solve the problem ).
SELECT bla bla bla
FROM current_campaign
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM current_campaign )
AND bla bla bla
UNION
SELECT bla bla bla
FROM last_campaign
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM current_campaign)
AND bla bla bla

Seems good?

Answer (score 3):

Since at most 1 row per view seems to be given, there is a very simple and cheap solution:

```
-- CREATE VIEW contributors AS
TABLE  current_campaign
UNION ALL
TABLE  last_campaign   -- assuming matching row type
LIMIT  1;              -- applies to the whole query
```

If that was an over-simplification:

```
-- CREATE VIEW contributors AS
SELECT * FROM current_campaign
WHERE  ...
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM last_campaign
WHERE  ...
LIMIT  1;
```

It would be a waste of time to count rows in `current_campaign` or run an `EXISTS` semi-join, since `LIMIT 1` does everything you need automatically. Postgres stops executing as soon as enough rows are found to satisfy the `LIMIT` (1 in this case). You'll see "(never executed)" in the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for any later `SELECT` in the list. See links below for more.

This is an implementation detail that only works for `UNION ALL` (not `UNION`) and without an outer `ORDER BY` or other clauses that would force Postgres to consider all rows. I would expect other RDBMS to behave the same, but I only *know* about Postgres. It's *guaranteed* to work in all versions up to the current 9.5.

About the short syntax `TABLE current_campaign`:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM in psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from-in-psql/30276023#30276023)

Related, with more explanation, the same a bit more verbose:

- [Way to try multiple SELECTs till a result is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339715/way-to-try-multiple-selects-till-a-result-is-available/14365613#14365613)
- [Sum results of a few queries and then find top 5 in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528787/sum-results-of-a-few-queries-and-then-find-top-5-in-sql/8528920#8528920)

Comment: This is a really clever solution but I'm curious... given your statement that "Postgres stops executing as soon as enough rows are found"... does Postgres guarantee the default order of a UNION ALL will always evaluate the lead table first? I ask because I've seen evidence that this order of evaluation is not necessarily guaranteed for some other RDBMS UNION statements (for instance SQL Server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421049/sql-server-union-what-is-the-default-order-by-behaviour)

Comment: @Erwin  May be using ``LIMIT`` for this problem is better than ``COUNT`` (still not sure) but I think using ``LIMIT`` to filter row is not a good idea! Correct me if I tell something wrong.

Comment: @DanK: I added some more to clarify the scope of the solution.

Comment: @DanK: Oracle 12c will run both `select` statements in parallel when using `union all` so I guess it would not work there. I assume that it won't work if future Postgres versions either, once Postgres starts using parallel execution as well (although that is probably still some years in the future)

Comment: @mmuzahid: Consider the additions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Postgres is in the process of implementing parallel execution. [Robert Haas is leading the work on it.](http://rhaas.blogspot.co.at/2015/11/parallel-sequential-scan-is-committed.html) But I am pretty sure this will *never* stop working. Performance characteristics may change ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I know there will be parallel execution in 9.6 that's why I added that comment (btw: we would lose the performance benefit, not turn it loose)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Thank you for the additional information.. it is a very interesting topic.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thank you for the comment... I work mostly with Oracle 11G currently so your point is well taken.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `view` or `table`.  `Vision` isn't really a SQL vocabulary term.  Here is one way using `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select cc.*
from current_campaign cc
union all
select lc.*
from last_campaign lc
where not exists (select 1
                  from current_campaign cc
                  where cc.campaignId = lc.campaignId
                 );
```